# JQuery self closing an li which has been created at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery code that's adding list items at runtime:

```
function addlistitem() {

$('#mylist ul').append(`
   <li class="list-group-item">
    <button onclick="selfclose()">Del</button>
       Some Text Here
  </li>`); 

}
```

And the html is:

```
<div id='mylist'>
  <ul class="list-group"></ul>
</div>
```

How can I get the added list items to self close when its button is clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by "self close"?

Comment: when I click the list items button I need it to hide

Comment: You need to call `selfclose(this)` so the function will know which element to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `this` to `selfclose`. Then use that to find the enclosing `li` and remove it.

```js
function addlistitem() {

  $('#mylist ul').append(`
   <li class="list-group-item">
    <button onclick="selfclose(this)">Del</button>
       Some Text Here
  </li>`);

}

$("#add").click(addlistitem);

function selfclose(el) {
  $(el).closest("li").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mylist'>
  <ul class="list-group"></ul>
</div>
<button id="add">Add LI</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the inline `onclick=""` which I always discourage, the jQuery could be rewritten as:

```js
const $myList = $('#mylist ul'); // Cache your reusable static elements

const addListItem = (cont) => $('<li/>', {
  appendTo: $myList,
  'class': 'list-group-item',
  html: typeof cont === 'string' ? cont : 'Some <b>HTML</b> content Here',
  prepend: $('<button/>', {
    text: '\u2715',
    title: 'Remove list item',
    click() {
      $(this).closest('li').remove()
    }
  })
});

$("#add").on('click', addListItem);

// Additional example: Create some LI on app init:
addListItem("I'm created <b>on init</b>");
addListItem(":) me too!");
```

```html
<button id="add">INSERT NEW</button>
<div id='mylist'><ul class="list-group"></ul></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```